# Failed to create jar or exe for javafx project

Tags: maven, javafx, java-14, jpackage

so i want to create the exe file for my javafx project. So referred to the package github. So i took that project from github https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX and then when I am writing this command mvn clean install has they have written in there readme i am getting following error

this is a log

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (Build Native Windows App) @ main-ui ---
 9 File(s) copied
    1 file(s) copied.
detecting required modules
 The system cannot find the path specified.
detected modules:
creating java runtime image
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
  org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:804)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:751)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:313)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Reactor Summary for parent 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.874 s]
 [INFO] module1 ............................................ SUCCESS [  3.909 s]
 [INFO] module2 ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.939 s]
  [INFO] main-ui ............................................ FAILURE [  7.053 s]
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.064 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-07T17:18:12+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (Build Native Windows 
 App) on project main-ui: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit va
  lue: 1) -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
 org.codehaus.mojo:exec- 
   maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (Build Native Windows App) on project main-ui: Command execution f
ailed.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build 
(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:326)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build 
(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:804)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:751)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:313)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build 
(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following 
articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
 [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
 [ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :main-ui
```

my pom

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>main-ui</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <client.version>1.0.0</client.version>
    <exec.maven.plugin.version>1.6.0</exec.maven.plugin.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.dlsc.jpackagefx</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dlsc.jpackagefx</groupId>
        <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dlsc.jpackagefx</groupId>
        <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.dlsc.jpackagefx.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os><family>windows</family></os>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <version>${exec.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>Build Native Windows App</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
                        <executable>build_app.bat</executable>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <APP_VERSION>
                                ${client.version}
                            </APP_VERSION>
                            <PROJECT_VERSION>
                                ${project.version}
                            </PROJECT_VERSION>
                        </environmentVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And i can't understand the jpackage that was giving in github so please help and give me some tutorial regrading that i want to build an exe file